# How to avoid a task to block the main thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, multitasking

Suppose you have the following code:

```
Action action = () =>
{
  MethodThatReadSomeDataFromExternalHardware();
};

Task.Run(action);
```

The MethodThatReadSomeDataFromExternalHardware() method connects to a hardware device and return some data.

Which kind of device is not relevant to the problem.

Now, if that hardware is disconnected, the MethodThatReadSomeDataFromExternalHardware() methodh get stuck trying to connect.

Well... the problem is that when that method is stuck, the main thread is also stuck, until the hardware timeout occur.

Is there a way to avoid this? Of course, that is only one atomic method, so I cannot add inside it a loop or something in order to allow message processing in the main thread.

I suspect it is not possible but I am wondering if there is some C# instruction or Windows API to launch a parallel task that does not affect the main thread if that child process get stuck.

Regard
Jaime

Comment: Run this in an Async method to free it up from the UI thread. Also if you can detect when your hardware is disconnected then you could use a cancellation token in your task to cancel the task. A cancellation token will not cancel a task that has started though, however you can within the work the task is doing periodically check if that token has been cancelled and if so escape out of the work.

Comment: Are there no APIs that allow you to communicate asynchronously with your hardware? If you could change those synchronous calls in `MethodThatReadSomeDataFromExternalHardware` to async ones, you'd be in a much better place.

Comment: Why are you not `await`ing the `Task` returned by `Task.Run` ?

Comment: Task.Run is already using thread pool, so the problem with your code is in the calling thread. Can you provide the code which became stuck if there is no hardware?

Comment: I cannot.. because that method is only one method provided by the hardware manufacturer... that atomic method tries to open a connection to the TCP/IP device y get stuck if no connection can be established

Answer (score -2):

### Don't use Tasks

If you just want the method to complete and don't care whatever happens with the result -or- you are fine dealing with it in another thread; don't use `Tasks` as they are heavier than the `thread pool`, and require `.Net 4.5`.

### Use the Thread Pool

It may be a bit old and less fancy than `TPL` but it fits the bill. You use the [ThreadPool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx) much the same way you use `Task`. Instead of calling `Run` you call [QueueUserWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => {
   MethodThatReadSomeDataFromExternalHardwareAsync();
});
```

That way you enjoy both the lighter weight `ThreadPool` and your code is much more portable.

Comment: Any benchmarks for Tasks overhead? They are using the thread pool too, you know, so how do you measure? TPL is requiring .Net 4.5 too. Maybe you're confusing it with `async/await` which is from C#5.0 and .Net 4.6?

Comment: @VMAtm You miss what I said, tasks are TPL, the thread pool isn't. As for the performance difference - Tasks use wrappers around the threads and use the task scheduler. All of this in addition to using the thread pool itself. So unless all of this overhead amount to zero, yes, there is a small overhead.

Comment: @ISun This does not even answer the question. And we are waiting for those benchmark results.

Comment: Not sure why it is downvoted. That does answer on how to force something to run somewhere else as the main thread. Task do not ensure to be run elsewhere as the main thread.

Comment: See explanation here : https://code-maze.com/csharp-async-vs-multithreading/